# Composing MIME headers from scratch

Tags: c++, arrays, char, concatenation, mime

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically change information inside of a MIME header (which will be sent via SMTP) in C++ on Win7.

The below is the basic layout for a MIME header I am using.

```
char *payload_text[]={

  "Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:59:19 +1000\n",
  "To: " TO "\n",
  "From: " FROM "\n",
  "Cc: " CC "\n",
  "Message-ID: <sender@greenearth.com>\n",
  "Subject: This is a test with the payload as char\n",
  "\n",
  "Here is where the info goes\n",
  "\n ",
  NULL
  };
```

I would like to create a function that can change, for example, the subject of the header file when it is called, and return a char array (to my understanding). Here is how I am attempting this.

```
char *part1[]={

  "Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:59:19 +1000\n",
  "To: " TO "\n",
  "From: " FROM "\n",
  "Cc: " CC "\n",
  "Message-ID: <sender@greenearth.com>\n",
  "Subject: This is a test with the payload as char\n",
  "\n"
};

char *body [] = { "Test information.", 
                   "More test info" };

char *full_payload [ strlen(*part1) + strlen(*body) + 1 ];

strcat( *full_payload, *part1 );

strcat( *full_payload, *body );

cout << *full_payload;
```

When the payload is viewed, only the first string from both parts are shown

Output on console:

```
[several junk bytes]Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:59:19 +1000
Test information.
```

Whereas there should be an entire MIME header shown.

I cannot understand why this will not work. I believe the problem could be in that I do not understand the behaviour of {} in C++ nor can I find tutorials/example code that fall in this context (most seem to only address char arrays that don't have multiple strings seperated by commas inside of curved brackets).

Simply put, how can I append a string to the end of an existing chracter array of strings enclosed in curved brackets?

Thank you for reading, and advice would be recieved warmly.

Follow up:

Using the function to create a `std::string` and then converting it to a `const char *` it formats the MIME message as desired but fails to work with the libraries I am using for SMTP.

The final result must be in the form of `char* payload[] = {"strings, seperated, by, comma"};` and not `char *payload = "strings\nseperated\nby\ncommas"` which is what the `.c_str()` seems to do.

Does anyone know how to convert a `std::string` or `char* array[]` to a `char* payload[] = {"strings, seperated, by, comma"};` ? I think the brackets are the important part.

---

Simple question:

```
char *first_array[]  = { "one", "two" };

char *second_array[] = { "three", "four"};

char *final_array[ strlen(*first_array) + strlen(*second_array) + 1];

strcpy( *final_array, *second_array );

cout << *final_array;
```

How do I combine first_array and second_array into final_array? `strcopy()` and `strcat()` cause the program to crash when implemented like this. I think all I need to do is this basic operation.

Comment: If you cannot generate a dynamic Message-Id, just leave it out, and your MTA will assign a Message-Id.  If you need to know the Message-Id before you send the message, make sure you generate a unique ID for each message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `part1` and `body`, you are creating an array of strings, not a single string. This is similar to doing:

```
int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

The `{}` in this context are defining the items in the array. Thus `*part1` and `*body` only refer to the first line of each -- your code is copying the content of the first string in `part1` and `body`.

As for the junk bytes, `strcat` looks for the first null character and starts from there, replacing the null. Therefore, the first string should be appended using `strcpy`.

To properly handle this, note that `std::vector<const char *> mime` will have the same layout as `const char * mime[]`, so you can use this to build your array of strings:

```
void send_smtp_message(const char **message);

void build_mime_header(std::vector<const char *> &mime)
{
    mime.push_back("Date: ...");
    mime.push_back("From: " FROM);
    // ...
    mime.push_back(""); // for the newline between header and body
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<const char *> mime;
    build_mime_header(mime);
    mime.push_back("This is a test.");
    mime.push_back(NULL); // if the API requires this for end-of-data.
    send_smtp_message(&mime[0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a few compiler errors on the function declaration line of `build_mime_header` and the declaration for `std::vector` in dev c++. Looks like great code, what header files would this be reliant on? Thanks reece.

Comment: That code relies on the vector library, so you must write `#include <vector>`.

Comment: I choose your answer. This is what I was looking for as it works with my SMTP code and now I don't have to use extra MIME libraries, your experience with SMTP shows!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++, it's usually more secure and easier to use the `string` class from the standard library than using `char*`. C++ strings can be concatenated with the '+' operator. You can even convert c++ strings to a const char* with the `c_str()` member function.

Here's a function that kind-of does what you want:

```c
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string makeheader(std::string to, std::string from,
                       std::string cc, std::string subject)
{
    std::string header =
        "Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:59:19 +1000\n"
        "To: " + to + "\n"
        "From: " + from + "\n"
        "Cc: " + cc + "\n"
        "Message-ID: <sender@greenearth.com>\n"
        "Subject:" + subject + "\n";

    return header;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << makeheader("example@example.com", "example@example.com",
                            "example@example.com", "This is a test with the payload as char.");
};
```

Comment: You can convert any `std::string` to a `const char*` by doing `s.c_str()`, where s is the `std::string`. Check out the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: @JoaoMendesino: Use `c_str()` -- given `std::string mime;` and `void send_smtp(const char *data)` you can write `send_smtp(mime.c_str());` This will return a `const char *` to the string in `mime`.

Comment: Thank you very much user, I tried this but am having some issues converting it. Please see the appending info on the main text. Thank you.